# Get all families in hbase

Tags: hbase

I have a hbase table with

> Rows: word, Families: date

I want to get a scanner for all the words at the date 'd', how I can do this? So I don't want to specify the row value.

Answer (score 6):

Your question isn't clear where you are trying to get a scanner from, so I'm going to treat it like it's from the HBase command line. I've used the thrift library to interact with hbase and the CLI commands translate pretty obviously to that. I assume they will also translate well to any other interface you are getting a scanner for.

To get all the rows for a specific Column Family, you would use the following command

```
scan 'table_name', {COLUMNS => 'col_family:'}
```

For your case (minus 'table_name' 'cause I don't know that) it would look something like

```
scan 'yourTable', {COLUMNS => 'd:'}
```

That will return all rows in the column family `d`.

If you also want to specify what `RowKeys` to start at, it will look something like

```
scan 'yourTable', {COLUMNS => 'd:', STARTROW => 'word'}
```

That command will START at the row key `word` and get all rows after that point. If you want to limit it to just the `RowKey word`, you will also have to add the `STOPROW`. The `STOPROW` isn't included in the results. So you **CAN'T** do `scan 'yourTable', {COLUMNS => 'd:', STARTROW => 'word', STOPROW => 'word'}` as that will return nothing.
Specifying a `STOPROW` takes some knowledge of the RowKey values. I don't know your values, so it's hard to give a good example. What I often do is use the next character (in the ASCII set) for the last character of my start row. In your example I'd try

```
scan 'yourTable', {COLUMNS => 'd:', STARTROW => 'word', STOPROW => 'wore'}
```

I'm not going to promise this will work all the time, but it is likely to work in most cases. Perhaps all cases, I just haven't worked it out. :)

Hopefully that helps.

A good resource for HBase shell commands is http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about using the scan command of the Java API

If I understand your structure correctly you don't currently have a way to retrive words by date without a full table scan. - you can [setFilter](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setFilter%28org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.Filter%29) on the scan but it will still have to go to each row to check that

You didn't specify but I'd guess each word can occur in many dates (if you meant you have a family for each date then note that it isn't recommended to have more than 2-3 families)

If you want a relatively efficient way to store that I'd suggest you change your structure to 
Key Word0xDate and store the date in the the TimeStamp and then some 1 byte value as the data (so that a row will exist)
Storage-wise it would be the same as you current solution (plus 2 bytes which you can offset by shortening the family and qualifier names) and you'd be able to get a scan for a timestamp or a range of timestamps ([setTimestamp](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeStamp%28long%29) and [setTimeRange](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setTimeRange%28long,%20long%29) respectively) which well be more efficient as hbase will skip files where irrelevant timestamps are stored)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
     HTable t = new HTable(conf,"YourROW");
     ResultScanner scanner = t.getScanner(new Scan());    
     for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) 
     {
           if (rr.getValue("YourFamily" , "YourQualifier").equals(Bytes.toBytes("d"))
           {
                Get g = new Get(key);
                Result row = t.get(g);
                System.out.println("" + row.toString()); //print all data from this row
           }
     }
```